# Chrome installed takes Spanish as a default language

Tags: google-chrome

could you please help me with a Chrome install question?

I have the Chrome (Internet browser) installed but it looks like in Spanish. No matter how many times it’s uninstalled and reinstall, it’s still in Spanish.

My computer’s setting is English and most of the applications are in English. I am not a Spanish speaker and don’t use Spanish at all.

Why the Chrome installed takes Spanish as a default language? How can I have it corrected (not every time goes into the Chrome language setting)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Windows, go directly to chrome:settings/languages and add UK or US English to the list and set it as Chrome language.

See
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/173424?hl=en and
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/173424?hl=es , 
then see screenshots in https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/chrome/bITi8KHO8xI/ .

Answer (score 0):

Some information might be helpful when change the default language from Spanish to English:

Click on the menu, go to "Configuracion", in the search box, key in "idiomas", click on the "Configuracion de idioma y de introduccion de texto...".

Click on "Anadir", in the pop-up drop-down box, choose the English type, click "Aceptar". ("ingles - English" in general not working at my case, so choose the country specific one)

Remove the unwanted ones. Pictures below show the steps.

[image]

[image]